# Replicate BGVAR plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to replicate this plot generated in the package `BGVAR` with `ggplot2`.

Here is some information on the `plot` command of `BGVAR`: https://github.com/mboeck11/BGVAR/blob/master/R/plot.R (more specifically, check `plot.bgvar.irf`).

From the vignette, consider this example:

```
set.seed(1)
library(BGVAR)
data(eerData) 
model.ssvs.1<-bgvar(Data=eerData, 
                    W=W.trade0012,
                    draws=100,
                    burnin=100,
                    plag=1,
                    prior="SSVS",
                    hyperpara=NULL, 
                    SV=TRUE,
                    thin=1,
                    trend=TRUE,
                    h=0,
                    save.country.store=FALSE,
                    eigen=1.05
)

shocks<-list();shocks$var="stir";shocks$cN<-"US";shocks$ident="chol";shocks$scal=-100
irf.chol.us.mp<-irf(model.ssvs.1,shock=shocks,n.ahead=24,save.store=TRUE)
plot(irf.chol.us.mp,resp="US.y")
```

This code generates this plot, which I would like to replicate in `ggplot2`:

[image]

The data can be obtained by:

```
df <- plot(irf.chol.us.mp,resp="US.y")
```

How to achieve the same plot with `ggplot2`, using `df`?

Any help is very welcome. Thank you in advance!

EDIT

So far, I got here:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

US.y <- plot(irf.chol.us.mp,resp="US.y") %>% 
  data.frame() %>%
  mutate(steps = seq(from = 0, to = 24))

ggplot(US.y, aes(x = steps)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = median)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(y = low25)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(y = high75)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype='dotted', col = 'red') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

I am struggling with the polygons.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at geom_ribbon. Seems more appropriate than using geom_polygon

Comment: In the new version 2.5.3 the plot command for the 'bgvar.irf' object now returns a list with the plotted data. See also here: https://github.com/mboeck11/BGVAR/blob/master/NEWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues. The first problem is that the plot method from BGVAR only exports back the 25% and 75% confidence limits.  Wheras the plot also has a ribbon showing the 16% and 84% confidence limits.

To obtain these additional data points, I wrote a slightly altered version of the package's plot function, that returns both these limits in a list.  There might be a simpler way to obtain these using the package functions, but I'm not familiar with BGVAR.

```
f = function (x, ..., resp = NULL, shock.nr = 1, cumulative = FALSE) 
{
  oldpar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
  on.exit(par(oldpar))
  if (length(shock.nr) != 1) {
    stop("Please select only one shock.")
  }
  posterior <- x$posterior
  varNames <- dimnames(posterior)[[1]]
  varAll <- varNames
  cN <- unique(sapply(strsplit(varNames, ".", fixed = TRUE), 
                      function(x) x[1]))
  vars <- unique(sapply(strsplit(varNames, ".", fixed = TRUE), 
                        function(x) x[2]))
  if (!is.null(resp)) {
    resp.p <- strsplit(resp, ".", fixed = TRUE)
    resp.c <- sapply(resp.p, function(x) x[1])
    resp.v <- sapply(resp.p, function(x) x[2])
    if (!all(unique(resp.c) %in% cN)) {
      stop("Please provide country names corresponding to the ones of the 'bgvar.irf' object.")
    }
    cN <- cN[cN %in% resp.c]
    varNames <- lapply(cN, function(x) varNames[grepl(x, 
                                                      varNames)])
    if (all(!is.na(resp.v))) {
      if (!all(unlist(lapply(resp, function(r) r %in% varAll)))) {
        stop("Please provide correct variable names corresponding to the ones in the 'bgvar' object.")
      }
      varNames <- lapply(varNames, function(l) l[l %in% 
                                                   resp])
    }
    max.vars <- unlist(lapply(varNames, length))
  }
  else {
    varNames <- lapply(cN, function(cc) varAll[grepl(cc, 
                                                     varAll)])
  }
  for (cc in 1:length(cN)) {
    rows <- max.vars[cc]/2
    if (rows < 1) 
      cols <- 1
    else cols <- 2
    if (rows%%1 != 0) 
      rows <- ceiling(rows)
    if (rows%%1 != 0) 
      rows <- ceiling(rows)
    par(mar = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$mar, mfrow = c(rows, cols))
    for (kk in 1:max.vars[cc]) {
      idx <- grep(cN[cc], varAll)
      idx <- idx[varAll[idx] %in% varNames[[cc]]][kk]
      x <- posterior[idx, , shock.nr, c("low25", "median", 
                                        "high75"), drop = TRUE]
      y <- posterior[idx, , shock.nr, c("low16", "median", 
                                        "high84"), drop = TRUE]
      if (cumulative) {
        x <- apply(x, 2, cumsum)
        y <- apply(y, 2, cumsum)
      }
      b <- range(x, y)
      b1 <- b[1]
      b2 <- rev(b)[1]
      matplot(x, type = "l", col = c("black", BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$col.50, 
                                     "black"), yaxt = "n", xaxt = "n", lwd = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$lwd.line, 
              ylab = "", main = varAll[idx], cex.main = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$cex.main, 
              cex.axis = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$cex.axis, cex.lab = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$cex.lab, 
              lty = c(0, 1, 0), ylim = c(b1, b2))
      polygon(c(1:nrow(y), rev(1:nrow(y))), c(y[, 1], rev(y[, 
                                                            3])), col = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$col.75, border = NA)
      polygon(c(1:nrow(x), rev(1:nrow(x))), c(x[, 1], rev(x[, 
                                                            3])), col = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$col.68, border = NA)
      segments(x0 = 1, y0 = 0, x1 = nrow(x), y1 = 0, col = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$col.zero, 
               lty = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$lty.zero, lwd = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$lwd.zero)
      lines(x[, 2], col = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$col.50, lwd = 4)
      axis(2, at = seq(b1, b2, length.out = 5), labels = format(seq(b1, 
                                                                    b2, length.out = 5), digits = 1, nsmall = 1), 
           cex.axis = 1.2, las = 1)
      axisindex <- seq(1, nrow(x), by = 4)
      axis(side = 1, las = 1, at = axisindex, labels = c(0:nrow(x))[axisindex], 
           cex.axis = 1.6, tick = FALSE)
      abline(v = axisindex, col = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$col.tick, 
             lty = BGVAR:::bgvar.env$plot$lty.tick)
    }
  }
  return(invisible(list(x,y)))
}
```

Now that we have these in a list, we can convert to a data.frame and plot using `geom_ribbon` (rather than geom_polygon which you had)

```
df1 <- f(irf.chol.us.mp,resp="US.y")

df1 <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, df1)[,-5]
df1$steps = seq_len(NROW(df1))

ggplot(df1, aes(x = steps)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=low16, ymax=high84), fill='grey80') +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=low25, ymax=high75), fill='grey50') +
  geom_line(aes(y = median)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype='dotted', col = 'red') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24)) +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: The changed function works flawless. I was wondering why there were only three variables extracted from the original BGVAR plot. Your new function solves this puzzle by gathering also the other confidence limits. Thank you very much for your answer, @dww! This is very helpful.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, please. To return all confidence bands, you changed ```x``` to ```list(x,y)``` in the ```return(invisible(``` (last line of code)?